# Create a feature in pandas based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, technical-indicator, zerocrossing

I have the following dataset:

```
data = {'ROC_9':  [0.006250, 0.087230, 0.045028, 0.165738, -0.006993, -0.432736, -0.11162, 0.057466, 0.203138, -0.008234]}

price_data = pd.DataFrame (data)
```

It is an indicator about a stock price, namely rate of change.

I want to write a code that creates a new feature (column) on the pandas data frame when a current feature on the pandas data frame goes from positive to negative, or vice versa.

It is easier explained through an example: lets use the feature `ROC9`.

I create a new variable called `ROC9_signal` and set it equal to `0`:

```
`price_data['ROC9_signal'] = 0`
```

When `ROC_9` goes from `negative` to `positive`, I want to change the `ROC9_signal` from `0` to `1`.

When `ROC_9` goes from `positive` to `negative`, I want to change the `ROC9_signal` from `0` to `-1`.

Looking at the data, I would like `ROC9_signal` to change from `0` to `-1`, since the value has gone from `0.16` (`positive`) to `-0.006` (`negative`).

Looking at the data, I would like `ROC_9` signal to change from `0` to `1`, since the value has gone from -`0.11` (`negative`) to `0.05` (`positive`).

Looking at the data, I would like `ROC9_signal` to change from `0` to `-1`, since the value has gone from `0.20` (positive) to -`0.008` (`negative`).

It is only the row where the change happens that I want to change from 0 to 1 or 0 to -1, the other rows must remain at 0.

I will then apply this same logic to create a `momentum10_signal` column and a `chalkin_money_flow_signal` column. Therefore I want a solution that can be applied to different columns and not manually.

Thanks in advance for the help.

This is what the full data looks like:

[Full Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3labS.png)

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data in the form of text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: Apologies. I have provided some sample data now. Thanks @timgeb

Answer (score 0):

Try using np.where:

First create a column of 'ROC9_prev' using shift:

`price_data['ROC9_prev'] = price_data['ROC9'].shift(1)`

You may need to groupby a column before shifting in order to ensure that you're taking each stock's previous ROC9 as opposed to a different stock's current ROC9.

Then creating the signal column will follow like this:

```
price_data['ROC9_Signal'] = np.where(price_data['ROC9'] > 0 & price_data['ROC9_prev'] < 0, 1, 0)
price_data['ROC9_Signal'] = np.where(price_data['ROC9'] < 0 & price_data['ROC9_prev'] > 0, -1, 0)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
data = {'ROC_9':  [0.006250, 0.087230, 0.045028, 0.165738, -0.006993, -0.432736, -0.11162, 0.057466, 0.203138, -0.008234]}

price_data = pd.DataFrame (data)
price_data['ROC9_signal'] = 0
price_data
```

Use Boolean selection to find the two different crossings:

```
 ZeroCrossing1=price_data.ROC_9.ge(0)&price_data.ROC_9.shift(1).le(0)#from 0 to 1
 ZeroCrossing2=price_data.ROC_9.ge(0)&price_data.ROC_9.shift(-1).le(0)# from 0 to -1.
```

Put the Zerocrossing likely outcomes into a list

```
 ZeroCrossingOutcomes=[1,-1]
```

Conditionally calculate `price_data['ROC9_signal']` using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
price_data['ROC9_signal']=np.select([ZeroCrossing1,ZeroCrossing2],ZeroCrossingOutcomes,0)
print(price_data)
```

Alternatively use nested `np.where(if condition, ye, else no)`

```
price_data['ROC9_signal']=np.where(ZeroCrossing1,1,np.where(ZeroCrossing2,-1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! This works very nicely. Appreciate it!